# How to run the median function on counts in a table or data frame?

Tags: r

Im working with sample of data that looks like the following; mind you the original data frame is a lot bigger:

```
    vehicle id  trip code
       1          abc
       1          bcd
       1          ghy
       3          lhy
       3          gfy
       6          awl
       6          rhr
```

I've turned it into a table in order to see the frequency of trips that each unique vehicle has had.

```
  vehicle id    Trip (freq)
      1         3
      3         2
      6         2
```

I would like to calculate the median of each vehicle, in order to later average them. Should i approach this by running a script on the data frame or is there a way to do it on the frequency in the table by telling R to expand 3 into [1,2,3] and 2 into [1,2] and then running the median on these expansions?

I have the following code in mind, but I'm not sure if this is the best way to approach:

```
TRIPS_28$vehicle_id %>%
group_by(TRIPS_28$vehicle_id) %>%
median(count(TRIPS))
```

Appreciate the help!

Comment: I don't understand what you're calculating the median of?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have data like this:

```
(dat <- data.frame(vehicleID = c(1, 3, 6), Trip = c(3, 2, 2)))
#   vehicleID Trip
# 1         1    3
# 2         3    2
# 3         6    2
```

It sounds like you now want to take the median of `[1, 2, ..., t]` for every value `t` in the column `Trip`. The median of the sequence `[1, 2, ..., t]` is `(t+1)/2`, so you could simply do:

```
dat$median <- (dat$Trip + 1) / 2
dat
#   vehicleID Trip median
# 1         1    3    2.0
# 2         3    2    1.5
# 3         6    2    1.5
```